# OnNmeaMessageListener is not working even when called using the addNmeaListener

Tags: java, android, listener

This is the Interface which I'm using to get the Nmea and the altitude but when the onNmeaMessageListener is being called it does not execute it. I'm calling it using gpsManager which is  LocationManager variable,
the code neither works nor shows up as an error.

```
OnNmeaMessageListener onNmeaMessageListener = (nmea, timestamp) -> {
    Log.d("TrackManager", " NMEA : " + nmea + " TimeStamp : " + timestamp);
    if (trackStarted && !trackPaused) {
        if (nmea.startsWith("$GPGGA") || nmea.startsWith("$GPRMC")) {
            Log.d("TrackManager", "NMEA:" + nmea);
            try {
                out.write(nmea.getBytes());
                if (continuesMode) {
                    dataOut.write(nmea.getBytes());
                    bufferedNMEALines++;
                    if (bufferedNMEALines >= 10) {
                        flushContinuesTrack();
                        //dataOut.reset();
                        bufferedNMEALines = 0;
                    }
                } else {
                    outCompressed.write(nmea.getBytes());
                }
                // Log.d("TrackManager","NMEA:" + nmea);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            if (nmea.startsWith("$GPGGA")) {
                String[] nmeaSplit = nmea.split(",");
                if (nmeaSplit.length > 10) {
                    if (nmeaSplit[9].length() > 0) {
                        try {
                            mslAltitude = Float.parseFloat(nmeaSplit[9]);
                        } catch (NumberFormatException ex) {
                            mslAltitude = 0;
                        }
                    } else {
                        mslAltitude = 0.0f;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    if (markStarted && hasFix() && nmea.startsWith("$GPRMC")) {
        markProgress++;

        trackListener.onMarkProgress(markProgress);
        if (markProgress >= markMax) {
            stopMark();
        }
    }
};
```

This is how I'm calling it

```
gpsManager.addNmeaListener(onNmeaMessageListener);
```

**EDIT**

Declaration:

```
private LocationManager gpsManager;
```

Initialized in onCreate like so:

```
gpsManager = (LocationManager) 
getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
```

Also got Location updated:

```
gpsManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.PASSIVE_PROVIDER, 
GPS_UPDATE_TIME, 0, gpsListener);
```

Comment: Please share any other parts of your code which reference `gpsManager`.

Comment: I added them to the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NMEA strings come from live GPS receivers; they're not cached by the OS. `LocationManager.PASSIVE_PROVIDER` is not going to turn on the GPS, so that choice of provider is inappropriate for this use case. Try `GPS_PROVIDER` instead.

Comment: Thank u @greeble31 this worked just fine,although what if I use the `NETWORK_PROVIDER` ?

Comment: You're welcome, don't forget to accept this answer :)   You could test it, and answer that question for yourself, but you must understand that NMEA is a very GPS-specific technology. The NETWORK_PROVIDER doesn't use that; it's just guessing your location based on the SSIDs of nearby WiFi/cell networks.